# PHP CI: Undefined property -> Calling a private function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have written a private function that allows me to call the name of the object that is being called for when I edit it but for some strange reason it is being picked up as an Undefined property why?

**Troublesome Line:**

```
$data['pageTitle'] = 'Edit '.$this->fieldTitle.' ';
```

**Function:**

```
private function fieldTitle($id)
{
    $this->uri->segment(4);

    $information = $this->form_model->showFieldInformation();

    foreach ($information as $feild) {

        $feildName = $feild->name;

    }
    return $fieldName;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two mistakes:

fieldTitle should be a function `$this-><fieldTitle()` and not a variable `$this->fieldTitle`

There is a typo in:

```
foreach ($information as $feild) {

    $feildName = $feild->name;

}
return $fieldName;
```

you are mistyping `$fieldName` and `$feildName`

Answer (score 0):

```
$data['pageTitle'] = 'Edit '.$this->fieldTitle.' ';
```

Should be

```
$data['pageTitle'] = 'Edit '.$this->fieldTitle().' ';
```

Forgot the `()`